# Seeing two projects under one repo; expect to see only one

Tags: git, github

Am new to Git and still working things out. Why do I see **TestProject** *and* **WebAppWithSeleniumTest** both underneath the **TestProject** repo but not the other way around?

In my GitHub account, I have created and populated two public repositories:

https://github.com/robertmarkbram/TestProject
https://github.com/robertmarkbram/WebAppWithSeleniumTest

Each time I followed the same pattern:

1. Create the project in Eclipse.
2. Create a repo of the same name in GitHub.
3. Add the project to a local Git repo.
4. Push the project to the remote GitHub repo I created.

But as described above, under the **TestProject** repo I see **TestProject** *and* **WebAppWithSeleniumTest**.

[image: under the **TestProject** repo I see **TestProject** *and* **WebAppWithSeleniumTest**]

However, under the **WebAppWithSeleniumTest** repo I only see **WebAppWithSeleniumTest** (as expected).

[image: Under the **WebAppWithSeleniumTest** repo I only see **WebAppWithSeleniumTest** (as expected)]

Have I done something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked this out. I had added both projects locally to the same repository. So that when I committed the second repository remotely, it committed the contents of both projects.

Comment: I wrote up here how to use Eclipse local and remote Git repos: http://robertmarkbramprogrammer.blogspot.com.au/2014/10/add-eclipse-project-to-local-and-remote.html